# how to validate first the 2 file name, before comparing the content?

Tags: java

this code is used to compare the content of 2 text files,
but i need to validate first, that the names of those 2 file is not same.

can you help me to fix this code?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class compare { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

      try{
        FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(args[1]);

        if(args.length != 2)
            throw (new RuntimeException("Usage : java compare <filetoread> <filetoread>"));

        if(args[0]==args[1]){
           System.out.print("File name is identical");
        }
         else {
           while (true) {  
             int a = file1.read();
             int b = file2.read();
             if (a!=b) { 
               System.out.print("File do not match");
               break; 
             }
             else{
               System.out.print("Files match");
               break;
             }
           }
         }
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.print("File tidak ada");
      } 
      catch(IOException e){
        System.out.print("IO Error");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(args[0].equals(args[1]))
```

would help to compare the content of the String rather than their addresses.

Actually

```
 if(file1.getCanonicalPath().equals(file2.getCanonicalPath())
```

is better (if you can get File objects '`new File(arg[0])`', which can then be used as an argument for your `FileInputStream` objects): you will compare two canonical normalized path, rather than two String entered by a user with potential lowercase/uppercase differences for instance. See [`getCanonicalPath()` javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()):

> A canonical pathname is both absolute and unique.  The precise definition of canonical form is system-dependent.  This method first converts this pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the `getAbsolutePath()` method, and then maps it to its unique form in a system-dependent way.  This typically involves removing redundant names such as "`.`" and "`..`" from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on Microsoft Windows platforms).

Comment: @Vonc: getAbsolutePath() does NOT give you a 'canonical' normalized path.

Comment: @Stephen C: I just see your comment now. I know. I was busy fixing my answer while you were writing your own post.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
if (file1.getCanonicalPath().equals(file2.getCanonicalPath()) {
   // the arguments refer to the same file.
}
```

Note that unlike `File.getAbsolutePath()`, the `File.getCanonicalPath()` method resolves "." and ".." pathnames, resolves symbolic links on Unix/Linux and converts Windows drive letters to standard case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
args[0].equals(args[1])
```